# Android Manifest Running Multiple Processes Is this method efficient or correct?

Tags: android, performance, android-manifest

Oh so here is a sample of my manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.x.x">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.Welcome_"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.MainActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.ImageActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.SettingsActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.CollectionActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.HowtoActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.ABrowseACF_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.x.x.ABrowseACC_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now due to the way my app works I need another roughly 10 more activities to handle functions. Now is this the correct way to do things? Just mass adding to the manifest? Because I tried loading an intent without declaring the activity and OFC it broke the app because it could not find it.

Is this just basically "read from these locations" kind of situation? I was just thinking of performance. Do they not load until called via intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Each activity must be declared in manifest** because each activity is instantiated by android system from manifest file, that approach permit you to start every activity form every place(another app, adb shell etc.) as independent module. Activities are not loaded until you(or system) not call it via intent, so dont worry about performance, android take care of that, even unused activities which are no more visible can be recycled by system(of course if activity is not marked by special [rules](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)). There are a lot of solutions to avoid multiple activities in application, just use Fragments, Dialogs or custom views.

But if you like multiple activities you can split your app in multiple gradle modules(android libraries), every module will contain their own activities. Is a cool programming concept, the code must be modulated in independent logic groups.